# How to install AQM algorithms in ns3

Tags: ns-3, congestion-control

I am new to ns3 and trying a way to add Active Queue Management Algorithms in my code. I was wondering how could I implement them on my topology.

I tried implementing them through netdevcontainer, but it was showing a sigsegv error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the error you are getting but to install Queuing Disciplines (AQM algorithms) ,initially you need to have a NetDevContainer of the nodes you want to install the algorithm on like
`NetDeviceContainer internalNet;`

Then install the AQM algorithm using the following code :

`std::string aqmAlgo = "ns3::CoDelQueueDisc";

```
QueueDiscContainer queueDiscs;

TrafficControlHelper tch;   //AQM implementation

tch.SetRootQueueDisc (aqmAlgo);

queueDiscs = tch.Install(internalNet);`
```

Also don't forget to include the following header files:

```
#include "ns3/traffic-control-module.h"
```

Then it should work fine,

Chinmay